# Calculate line endpoint with rotation of a Cone 3D

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to rotate a Line to the destination, where a cone is pointing to.

In the snippet below i have a basic ThreeJs Cone and a line, which is at the moment hard coded to stick out vertikal. I want to be able to rotate the cone and the Line is like an laserbeam, which is sticking out at the top. Here is an example image for 2D
[image: Example Image].
My goal is to do this in 3D. My overall problem is, that i can only set the points of the Line and not the Rotation.

I know i can get the roation of the cone with `cone.rotation`. But i didn't managed to calculate the right POsition of the end point of the line

In the Snippet you can rotate the cone by holding down the left mouse button.

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene();

//Lights
scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight(0x808080, 0x606060));
let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
light.position.set(0, 6, 0);
scene.add(light);
//camera
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 2);
scene.add(camera);

//Cone
let cone = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.ConeBufferGeometry(0.2, 0.5, 20, 20),
    new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000,
        roughness: 0.7,
        metalness: 0.0,
    })
);
scene.add( cone );

//line
var points = [];
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().setFromPoints( points );
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff
});
let line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add( line );



//renderer with loop
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function render() {
    updateLine();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
renderer.setAnimationLoop(render)



document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
let middleDown = false;

let mouseStart = {
    x:0,
    y:0
}
let cur = {
    start : {
        rot: {
            x:0,
            y:0,
            z:0
        }
    }
}

document.onmousedown = function (e){
    if (e.button == 0)
            middleDown = true;
    
    
    mouseStart.x= e.pageX;
    mouseStart.y= e.pageY;
    //Save cur
    cur.start.rot.x = cone.rotation.x;
    cur.start.rot.y = cone.rotation.y;
    cur.start.rot.z = cone.rotation.z;
    return false;
}
document.onmouseup = function (e){
    if (e.button == 0)
            middleDown = false;
}
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    let pos = {
        x: e.pageX,
        y: e.pageY
    }
    if(middleDown){
        cone.rotation.x = cur.start.rot.x + (pos.y/350 - mouseStart.y/350);
        cone.rotation.z = cur.start.rot.z + (pos.x/350 - mouseStart.x/350);
    }
}




function updateLine() {
    
    line.geometry.vertices[0] = cone.position;
    
    //Here i want to update the new Line end
    line.geometry.vertices[1] = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 )
    
    line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to add the line to the cone, so you'll get the line rotated/translated/scaled with the cone? Instead of `scene.add( line );` use `cone.add( line );`.

Comment: @prisoner849 Well thanks very much. If you want you can add a Awnser so i can acceppt it.